# Cannot open MSDTC service on computer. Access is denied

Tags: c#, .net, service, permissions

I'm trying to verify that my user has access to control the MSDTC service so that it can be started if turned off. Actually, the first step would be to just verify that it has been started and it isn't crucial to be able to start it.
The application is using .Net 4.0 and is therefore running under the new security model.

The following code works when running it with a user with required permissions but fails on the Stop() method for an ordinary user (non administrator):

```
     var permission = new ServiceControllerPermission(ServiceControllerPermissionAccess.Control, Environment.MachineName, "MSDTC");
     permission.Demand();  // Is this even considered in .Net 4.0?

     var MSDTC = new ServiceController("MSDTC", Environment.MachineName);
     MSDTC.Stop();   // Crashes with "Access is denied" for an ordinary user.
     MSDTC.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
     MSDTC.Start();
```

So, my questions is how do I verify that the user has the required permissions to run the operation? In general how do I check this for other resources like the register etc?

I have looked around quite a bit for a solution but haven't found anything. Of course I have read the MSDN documentation about the new security model but didn't find anything I could use there for this scenario.

Comment: Is there any reason not to wrap this in a try...catch block and catch the exception that would indicate the user doesn't have permission?

Comment: If I did that I would have to run the operation and the point is that a user should only have the option to run it if permitted. But of course, this is my fallback if I can't solve it.